# Why is $\mathbb{R}^n$ not a functional space?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Euclidian spaces have a topology, a norm, a metric, they are pretty strictly defined topological vector spaces.

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_space#Functional_analysis) multiple $\mathbb{R}$-based space is listed which are modified by differentiability conditions ($C_0,C_c,C^\infty,C^\omega,$ and their combinations).

**Why can't i just talk about *all* kinds of functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and treat it as a function space?**

I know they won't be nice to work at but still...

Comment: Technically $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a function space.

Comment: @DietrichBurde i accidentally used a different spelling :)

Comment: You mean, you are still using a different spelling :)

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a function space can be imagined as the set of functions from the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. It's just a bit boring is all..

Comment: You certainly can talk about the set of all functions from any set $X$ to any set $Y$, it's often written $Y^X$. The list of function spaces in the Wikipedia are particularly interesting subsets of $Y^X$ for appropriate $X$ and $Y$ that have been found to be interesting and useful. (Aside: I am answering the question in the body of your post, not the title: it's generally a good idea to use a title that matches the actual question.)

Comment: Thank you for the answers! @RobArthan i will look out for that, i was trying to elaborate and not repeat the same question.

Comment: @DietrichBurde aww schucks!

Comment: It's best to make the body of your question self-contained. Don't worry about repeating parts of the title.